# Windows 7 and F-Secure. Why won't conhost.exe leave me alone?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, process

I recently upgraded my main dev machine to Windows 7 x64 from Vista x64. Now, F-Secure Internet Security 2009 periodically tells me that conhost.exe is attempting to shut it down and asking if I want to block the operation or not. It doesn't seem to make any difference if I allow the operation or block it, some time (within minutes or maybe even hours) later, the same obtrusive dialog will interrupt me again.

It'll come as no surprise that the F-Secure site steadfastly refuses to acknowledge the problem.

Does anyone have any creative solutions to my annoying problem? Preferably without throwing away F-Secure!

Edit: In the end, F-Secure pointed me to their updated 2010 version. That's been behaving much better since!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend trying their upcoming 2010 version and see if that works around the issue at hand.

http://download.f-secure.com/estore/fs2010.exe

Answer (score 0):

It was worse than that for me. The popup kept coming back every few seconds regardless of how I responded, and it screwed up the Windows 7 update that is due right after installing Windows 7. Uninstalling F-secure and leaving it uninstalled allowed me to update windows.